# Converting a VK_CODE into a displayable string

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

When writing a Windows application, the documentation says that some VK_CODEs are displayable characters, like VK_OEM1 is "o with an umlaut". How can I go from the WPARAM of non-ASCII characters into a displayable string? I'm using UTF-16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for the [GetKeyNameText Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646300%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

It retrieves a string that represents the name of a key.

Answer (score 2):

> like VK_OEM1 is "o with an umlaut".

Maybe on your machine.  Not on mine, it is ';' or ':', depending on the Shift key state.  These are *virtual* key codes.  The ones that represent a typing key get converted to a character by ToUnicodeEx(), a function that takes a keyboard layout.  And of course you have the non-typing keys that produce no character at all, like VK_F1 or VK_NUMLOCK.  This gets a lot more complicated when the keyboard layout has dead keys, the kind you use to get a diacritic on top of a character.  That why the function also requires a keyboard state.

Avoid this like the plague, WM_CHAR is your friend.